# What is wrong with Tex live 2015 installation?

Tags: texlive

Tex live 2015 has finally arrived. I uninstalled 2014, download the setup exe, and expected to be able to use the newest version. Instead it gives me this

[image]

I tried several mirrors. All of them failed.

Comment: In order to reduce site overloading, a request to `mirror.ctan.org` is dispatched to one of several mirrors in your zone; you should wait for the mirrors to be all updated.

Comment: Just choose another mirror. For example the German mirrors (I am just downloading it) seem to work now

Comment: As a general, I never uninstall an old version of anything until I have the new version running -- and suitably tested. With TeXLive 2015 I will wait a few weeks before uninstalling TexLive 2014. (Of course, sometimes software requires you to uninstall the old version first but TeXLive is not in this category.)

Comment: I have 4 editions of TL installed on this machine!

Comment: I'm confused. My TeXLive 2014 would not proceed to allow me to add a package yesterday, forced me to upgrade if I wanted to do anything at all (via a single button press), which I did, and I now have 2015.

Comment: Downloading one huge iso file using the torrent network also works very well: https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-iso.html#torrent